# Is it possible to filter tweets as they are being scraped by number of retweets or likes in twint or getoldtweets3?

Tags: python, twitter, tweets

```
import twint

c = twint.Config()
c.Hide_output = True
c.Search = "TSLA"
c.Lang = "en"
c.Since = "2019-10-01 00:00:00"
c.Until = "2019-10-10 00:00:00"
c.Store_csv = True
c.Output = "TSLA.csv"

twint.run.Search(c)
```

This code takes a lot of time to execute and gets me 10,600 tweets, most of which add no value. I simply need tweets where retweets or likes are greater than a threshold. Unfortunately, documentation on twint and getoldtweets3 is quite light. Does anyone have any experience with this please?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
c.Lang = "en"
c.Search = "TSLA"
StartDate = "2019-10-01"
EndDate = "2019-10-10"
c.Since = StartDate
c.Until = EndDate
c.Filter_retweets = True 
c.Store_csv = True
c.min_likes = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include min_retweets:20 or min_faves:20 (specifying the threshold) in the c.Search object.

```
c.Search = "TSLA min_retweets:20"
```